# WriteToFile:atomically deprecate Warning

Tags: iphone, ios

I want write a textField value which is a user name to file named login.txt.

My code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// the path to write file
loginFilePath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.txt"];
NSString *userName=[nameText text];
[userName writeToFile:loginFilePath atomically:YES];
```

I get Warning as "wrtieToFile:atomically:" is deprecated.

Comment: Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

Answer (score 4):

Because it is deprecated, use:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error;
```

instead of `writeToFile:atomically`

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 11 `writeToFile:atomically` has been deprecated in favour of `- writeToUrl:error:`.

It seems like a lot of the old write/read methods have been deprecated for `NSArray` and the api has been simplified. So creating an `NSArray` from a file now uses `- initWithContentsOfURL:error:`.

Answer (score 0):

[The NSString documentation states that it's deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:)

> Writes the contents of the receiver to the file specified by a given
>   path. (Deprecated in iOS 2.0. Use writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error: instead.)

The documentation for the replacement method `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:).